# Would Google find my site more easily if I use a 301 re-direct or use two domains? (one as landing page and the other for the content)

Tags: seo, domains, domain-forwarding, landing-page

I have some webspace with two top level domains. I am programming an android app at the moment, which is a niche app. Because of this I need a good homepage with useful content for my users, so that they can find the content with google and can take a look to my app. The content will not only be about the app-topics. I want to use wordpress to create the landing page and the content-blog.

1. First Domain: Main field of the topic -> **www.main-field.com** (for example the whole fitness field.)
2. Second Domain: The app is only a subset of the main topic. -> **www.subset-app.com** (For example a healthy nutrition to get big muscles.)

Now I am thinking about my next steps:

- Should I use a URL forwarding? Which of the two domains should be my MAIN-page?
- Should I use both domains? So if I click on *BLOG/Content* I go to the **www.main-field.com** and the other way if I click on ***about the App*** I go to the **www.subset-app.com**

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You could possibly restate this as "Would Google find my site more easily if..."